# Floating Left and Right Arrows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having problems creating a view that has images stacked horizontally with little arrows centered in vertically in on the left and right side of the div containing the images for scrolling the view.

The arrows end up centered relative to the page, not the center image piece.

I am trying to make it look similar to this:
http://www.vanleeuwenicecream.com/

I would like the left and right arrows to be positioned with just CSS/HTML if possible.

Here is what I have so far:
https://github.com/thorkia/cssPositioningIssue

Any help would be appreciated

Note:

I can make the view scroll fine by changing the left margin on the div containing the images with js.  I removed that for the sample.  I just need to arrows positioned correctly

Comment: you might want to include where, in your code, the elements and styles in question are. Even better, isolate the issue and add the relevant code here, so those who are trying to help you doesn't have to sift through your codebase.

Comment: Create a code-snippet here, or on jsfiddle, and create what you have. HTML and CSS.

Comment: you need to provide the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.imagesContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.imageScrollers .imageScrollBack img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
}

.imageScrollers .imageScrollNext img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagesContainer">

  <div class="imageScrollers">
    <span class="imageScrollBack"><img src="dawdaw" alt=""></span>
    <span class="imageScrollNext"><img src="dawdaw" alt=""></span>
  </div>
</div>
```